# Issue with JSON request when using try_files

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to use `try_files` as suggested here https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html and for the same purpose.

I've made one change to it and it is to remove the `index.html` portion of the command so it looks as follows:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /;
}
```

In case part of my problem is that I removed `index.html` I'll note that I was getting the following error when I had it:

`rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html"`

As far as I can tell it is working as expected except that it is acting on JSON requests but not in the manner that I'd like. Instead of getting a JSON response I get what looks like any other page of my site but without content.

Tailing the logs I can see that when I hit `/foo.json` I'm redirected to `/` and checking the URL I can see that `/foo.json` has been `pushState`ed onto it.

Am I using `try_files` incorrectly here? If I'm not, is there a way to have it ignore JSON requests? I've tried putting the statement in a conditional that checks the content type but when I started the server I got the following error:

```
nginx: [emerg] "try_files" directive is not allowed here in
/tmp/passenger-standalone.15snfcb/config:110
```

Comment: Do you actually have a static file named `/foo.json` ? If not, then you need to pass such requests to your backend application. And of course you need to put `try_files` back to the way it was shown in the tutorial you linked.

Comment: I don't have a /foo.json static file I have a route which, when hit, makes a request to my Rails app and returns a JSON response. Could you elaborate on the 'And of course you need...'. It's working but I might have a blind spot.

Comment: There's a lot that doesn't make sense here, then. Please post the complete `server` block.

Comment: @MichaelHampton with the help of your comment I managed to get it working using `location ~ ".+json$" { passenger_enabled on; }`. It solves my problem but I don't trust that it is the best solution. The original block I had looked as follows: `location / { try_files $uri $uri/ /; }`. My JSON regex can be improved. I'm certain of that. But I still am unsure why I would _need_ to have `index.html`.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that I have BOTH blocks still. The original being the `location /` one.

Comment: Oh, I see, you're using embedded passenger. I would rather use a separate Rails app server, such as thin or puma.

Comment: Okay. Well thanks a lot! If you post your first comment as an answer I'll up vote since it led me to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Michael Hampton I came up with the following solution:

In my server block (unnecessary other blocks/commands removed):

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /;
}

location ~ ".+json$" { 
    passenger_enabled on; 
}
```

The regex is not thorough enough but satisfies the problem I was dealing with. I'd like to find a solution that uses the files content type instead of a regex.